# Why did nobody help Harry Potter when he sent sparks up in the maze?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Goblet of Fire movie Harry, soon after entering the maze, sends up his red sparks to forfeit. But nobody helps him and he has to continue the challenge.

Why could Harry not leave the maze?

Comment: He sends up sparks to highlight Fleur's position, not to ask for a rescue

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Periculum

Comment: Then why did nobody help fleur in the movie? She can be seen being dragged into the hedge

Comment: @JoshWhitfield Because it looks more dramatic, it's just movie "logic"...

Comment: @Richard: so it wasn't because they were schmucks?

Comment: @user13267 - In this instance, no.

Answer (score 17):

**Harry uses the spell to summon help for Fleur and Krum – he’s gone before help arrives.**

It varies slightly between the book and the film:

- In the book: He and Cedric encounter Krum under the influence of the Imperius Curse. After they stun him, they decide to send up red sparks so he can be picked up:

  > “No,” said Harry. “I reckon we should send up red sparks.
  >
  > Someone’ll come and collect him… otherwise he’ll probably be eaten by a skrewt.”
  >
  > “He’d deserve it,” Cedric muttered, but all the same, he raised his wand and shot a shower of red sparks into the air, which hovered high above Krum, marking the spot where he lay.
  >
  > — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 31 (*The Third Task*)

  They don’t stick around to see it happen – they press on towards the centre of the maze.

  He only hears Fleur’s scream, but doesn’t know where she was attacked.
- In the film: Harry finds Fleur as she’s been swallowed under the hedges, and throws up red sparks to get help, but almost immediately the hedges close in on him and he’s forced to flee. Cedric and Harry encounter and knock out Krum shortly afterward, but he doesn’t get any red sparks.

Presumably help did arrive in both cases, because they both come out alive – but Harry isn’t there to see it happen.

Answer (score 3):

He never used this spell to call help *for himself* in The Goblet of Fire. He only used it to call help *for Fleur and Viktor*.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way of telling *who* shot the sparks - they are just visual markers.  Whoever was responsible for pulling out any champion who got into trouble would just go to the rough location, and look around for whoever needed help.  If the sparks identified people rather than location, then Harry might have been dragged out and/or disqualified for shooting sparks, even though he intended to summon help for another champion.

As for why we didn't see anyone helping Fleur, out of universe it was likely for drama's sake, in universe... perhaps whoever was supposed to be helping was sabotaged by Crouch, maybe they couldn't see her under the hedge and thought whoever sent the sparks left, or maybe it just took time for whoever was watching to get in to help, and the screen wasn't looking when they got there.